# python Custom json conversion table JSONEncoder csv to json

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch

I'm trying to convert CSV to json for usage with elasticsearch.
Here is a sample csv:

`user,user_creation_time
UserName1,2018-02-21T15:57:53+00:00
UserName2,N/A`

array types: `user` - `str`,

`user_creation_time` - ISO Time or `str('N/A')`
The problem is that ElasticSearch ingest fails on value `N/A` because it expects type `date`.

I have more time fields with this issue (once it's date, once it's string). What is the best way to achieve this?

In the end the functionality should be like:

csv

`user,user_creation_time
UserName1,2018-02-21T15:57:53+00:00
UserName2,N/A`

python

`{"user":"UserName1","user_creation_time":"2018-02-21T15:57:53+00:00"}
{"user":"UserName2","user_creation_time":None}`

json

`{"user":"UserName1","user_creation_time":"2018-02-21T15:57:53+00:00"}
{"user":"UserName2","user_creation_time":null}`

What I do now is:

```
import csv

with open(csv_file, 'r') as inf:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inf.readlines())

print(json.dumps(tuple(reader)))
```

Comment: Ther is no need to use a `JSONEncoder` because Python `None` results in json `null` by default. So simple change `dict['user_creation_time'] = None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing the same as it was suggested by @stovfl.
And created this https://gist.github.com/1oglop1/9950b033dc655f675ebc11ac122ab815

Another dirty solution is replace values in string, convert it to json, dump json to string, replace different values and get correct structure when loaded again

```
with open(csv_file, 'r') as inf:
    file_content = inf.read()

no_na = file_content.replace('N/A', '').replace('not_supported', '')
rdr = csv.DictReader(no_na.splitlines())
records = json.dumps(tuple(rdr))
fixed_json = records.replace('""', "null").replace('"false"', "false").replace("'true'", "true")
print('jsn',records)
print(fixed_json)
print(json.loads(fixed_json))  # correct dict
```